# Item in String - Create new column

Tags: string, pandas, feature-engineering

So I have found some other answers to this question that involved conditionally selecting with operators but I haven't found a solution that involves contain statements.

What I am trying to accomplish is inside a dataframe

```
A     cat     ?
B     dog     ?
C     rat     ?
```

How do I set the third column to a value depending on whether the second column contains 'a'?

Comment: you can check `str.contains`

Answer (score 0):

Use `contains`:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.contains('a')
```

Output:

```
  Col0 Col1   Col2
0    A  cat   True
1    B  dog  False
2    C  rat   True
```